# I would like to do a scan with Ajax and jQuery to see if the name already exists in the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I would like to do a scan with Ajax and jQuery to see if the name already exists in the database, if there have to return a message.
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried yet? Share that with us.. so that we can help you better.. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to write some kind of web service interface on whatever server-side system you're using that has the database. Then, you could use jQuery getJson: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Your web service will return JSON and getJSON will automatically turn that back into a javascript object so your javascript code can make some kind of decision based on the results.

Note that javascript alone cannot interface with your database, you need to have some kind of http interface that ajax can connect to.